# Calculate how many ones in bits and bits inverting

Tags: c++, c, bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many 1s in an n-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611333/how-many-1s-in-an-n-bit-integer)

Hello

How to calculate how many ones in bits?

```
1100110 -> 4
101 -> 2
```

And second question:

How to invert bits?

```
1100110 -> 0011001
101 -> 010
```

Thanks

Comment: Many duplicates, e.g. [How many 1s in an n-bit integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611333/how-many-1s-in-an-n-bit-integer) and [What does this function do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265942/what-does-this-function-do). Also should really be two separate questions.

Comment: also should ask second question in a separate question anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can loop while the number is non-zero, and increment a counter when the last bit is set. Or if you are working on Intel architecture, you can use the `popcnt` instruction in inline assembly.

   ```
   int count_bit_set(unsigned int x) {
       int count = 0;
       while (x != 0) {
           count += (x & 1);
           x = x >> 1;
       }
       return count;
   }
   ```
2. You use the `~` operator.

Comment: Thank you! How to cout bits? I mean instead of 5 -> I want to see 101

Comment: Use `std::bitset` : `std::bitset<32> bitset(5); std::cout << bitset << std::endl;`.

Answer (score 5):

If you can get your bits into a `std::bitset`, you can use the `flip` method to invert, and the `count` method to count the bits.

Comment: +1: this ties in better with the question than `~`, flipping bits without rounding the number of bits up to the size of the data type.

Answer (score 4):

The book *Hacker's Delight* by Henry S Warren Jr. contains lots of useful little gems on computing this sort of thing - and lots else besides.  Everyone who does low level bit twiddling should have a copy :)

The counting-1s section is 8 pages long!

One of them is:

```
int pop(unsigned x)
{
    x = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    x = (x + (x >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
    x = x + (x >> 8);
    x = x + (x >> 16);
    return x & 0x0000003F;
}
```

A potentially critical advantage compared to the looping options already presented is that the runtime is not variable.  If it's inside a hard-real-time interrupt service routine this is much more important than "fastest-average-computation" time.

There's also a long thread on bit counting here:
[How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Answer (score 1):

Counting bits: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive

Inverting bits: `x = ~x;`

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, [Fast Bit Counting](http://gurmeet.net/puzzles/fast-bit-counting-routines/) has a few ways of doing it, the simplest being:

```
int bitcount (unsigned int n) {
   int count = 0;
   while (n) {
      count += n & 0x1u;
      n >>= 1;
   }
   return count;
}
```

For the second question, use the [´~´ (bitwise negation) operator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/as400clr103.htm).

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of set bits in a number you can use the hakmem parallel counting which is the fastest approach not using predefined tables for parallel counting:

http://tekpool.wordpress.com/2006/09/25/bit-count-parallel-counting-mit-hakmem/

while inverting bits is really easy:

i = ~i;

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat trikcy (but faster) solution would be:

```
int setbitcount( unsigned int x )
{
    int result;
    for( result=0; x; x&=x-1, ++result )
        ;
    return result;
}
```

Compared to sylvain's soultion, this function iterates in the loop only the number of set bits. That is: for the number 1100110, it will do only 4 iteration (compared to 32 in Sylvain's algorithm).

The key is the expression x&=x-1, which will clear the least significant set bit. i.e.:
1) 1100110 & 1100101 = 1100100
2) 1100100 & 1100011 = 1100000
3) 1100000 & 1011111 = 1000000
4) 1000000 & 0111111 = 0

Answer (score 1):

You can also inverse bits by [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)'ing them with some number. 
For example - inversing byte:
`INVERTED_BYTE = BYTE ^ 0xFF`

Answer (score 0):

```
How to calculate how many ones in bits?
```

[Hamming weight.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight)

```
How to invert bits?
```

`i = ~i;`